# Adding Name and Image at the bottom of Opentok Publisher's Stream and It should be visible on the Subscriber's end by default

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to develop an application with the help of OpenTok where I need to add Name of the user as well as the logo of my application on the publisher's **stream**. Why am I focusing on the Stream? The reason is if I use some kind of overlay on my publisher's window It would only be visible on my side but on the Subscriber's side, It would show the normal video stream from my camera. As I have archiving feature enabled on OpenTok it records my live streaming and stores it on my server so I can also not do the same overlay stuff on the subscriber side.

How can I achieve this thing?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For drawing some text and image over the stream your publisher is sending you have two alternatives:

1. You can build a [custom capturer](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Video-Driver) that will render the text and image over the byte buffer that represents each frame coming from the camera [just before providing](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/master/Custom-Video-Driver/CustomVideoDriverLib/src/main/java/com/example/tokbox/CustomVideoDriverLib/CustomVideoCapturer.java#L394) it to OpenTok. This way is a little bit challenging since you will probably need a library to render text and images into a raw YUV byte buffer.
2. You can render the contents of the camera to an Android View, and with the help of Android Layouts (FrameLayout will work well here) render the text and image using Android Views like TextView and ImageView. Once you have everything in place, your publisher will send the content of the composed Android View like in our [screen sharing sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Screen-Sharing).

Comment: But If we add screen sharing capturer in the publisher it stops opening camera as we have intercepted its default capturer. How to achieve both things in one capturer.

Comment: You will need a OT Publisher which will stream the contents of the Android View (screen sharing) and a non-Opentok code to capture the contents of the camera to a view. Said in other words, the code that puts the camera input into an Android View is not related to Opentok.

Comment: Hylian - The way you were suggesting to achieve the things is not working.  When I try to share the camera preview via Screen Sharing Capturer, OT will only send a blank window to the subscriber's end. Please review my sample and let me know where I am wrong.

Android sample - https://github.com/vineetsaxena/OTExample
iOS Sample - https://github.com/Parvind-Metadesign/opentoksample

Comment: Looking at the sample, the black screen is probably because the library you use to show the camera preview is using SurfaceViews and they cannot be captured as we do in the ScreenSharing sample. I recommend you to use Camera2 API directly and show the view in TextureViews instead.